# Clickable drop down menu in joomla

Tags: html, css, joomla

I have CSS(HTML) horizontal menu and everything is working properly, but when i touch with the mouse one of the menu "**listing**" is appear, but i want to make it clickable.

I try almost everything in this row:

```
.main-nav-ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

But without success...
I`m using Joomla and custom HTML CSS Javascript module.
I use this code:

https://github.com/shahbokhari/webdev/blob/master/Vertical-Drop-Down-Navigation-2015%202/vertical-drop-down-navigation-using-html-css-2015.html

I want when i click on ЧАСТИ ЗА LED ТАБЕЛИ to be able to see sub menus in this category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With css you can only handle hover(mouse enter and mouse out). to handle click you should use javascript:

```
$('.main-nav-ul li').click((e)=>{
  $(e.target).closest('li').toggleClass('toggled');
});
```

it will toggle (add/remove) `toggled` class of li element, when it's clicked.

then you should replace `li:hover` to `li.toggled` in css , to apply toggled styles when li has toggled class.

you can see this in [codepen](https://codepen.io/ya3ya6/pen/BeXRxd)

Comment: @AmirBll thanks for edit. i was wondering how to say that (codepen : codepen was awefull :p)